# How do i run tagged Feature/scenario/Examples in Webdriverio-cucumber/boilerplate?

Tags: typescript, cucumber, webdriver-io, gherkin

Hi _ if anyone can help here- I am trying to run a specific scenario with examples by using Cucumber tags- this is the expression I am using to run the tests built with Webdriver- Cucumber-boilerplate framework-

npx wdio run wdio.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression='@sanity and @stage'

When I use the above, nothing happens - i have defined the tag - '@Tag' at the feature level- so am expecting that all the scenarios within the feature file will get executed, however when i run the above command- nothing happens. Can someone please help?

npx wdio run wdio.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression='@Tag

```
Example:
@sanity
Feature: ICRM test
    As a user, I want to login with test website
    Scenario: login with credentials
        Given I open the url "<Link>"
        Then I expect that the title is "iCRM Login"
        When I set "<Username>" to the inputfield "#loginEmail"
        And  I click on the button "[role=button]"
        And  I set "<Password>" to the inputfield "#Password1"
        Then I click on the button "//button[contains(text(),'Log In')]"
        Then I wait on element "//body/div[@id='wrap']/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]" for 10000ms to be displayed
        @stage
        Examples:
            | Username                        | Password | Link                                             |
            | sameer.joshi@test.com | test5# | https://test.com/icrm/index.html |
        @Live
    Examples:
       | Username                        | Password | Link                                             |
        | sameer.joshi@test.com | Virtua5# | https://testlinkslive.com/icrm/index.html
```

|

Comment: did the below help

Answer (score 0):

There is one issue with your Feature file, that needs to be corrected.

As you are using `Examples:` as parametrisation for your scenarios, each scenario that utilises examples will require a `Scenario Outline` label before the title of the scenario.

It should look like similar to the following:

```
  @sanity
  Feature: ICRM test
  As a user, I want to login with test website

  Scenario Outline: login with credentials
    Given I open the url "<Link>"

    .... other steps

    Then I wait on element "//body/div[@id='wrap']/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]" for 10000ms to be displayed
    @ex1
    @stage
    @test
    Examples:
      | Username              | Password | Link                              |
      | sameer.joshi@test.com | stage5#  | https://stage.com/icrm/index.html |
    @ex2
    @live
    @test
    Examples:
      | Username              | Password | Link                                      |
      | sameer.joshi@test.com | virtua5# | https://testlinkslive.com/icrm/index.html |
    @ex3
    @adhoc
    @test
    Examples:
      | Username              | Password | Link                             |
      | sameer.joshi@test.com | test5#   | https://test.com/icrm/index.html |
```

The following should now work and only run the scenario example tagged with `@stage`:

`npx wdio run wdio.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression='@sanity and @stage'`

### Summary of Cucumber options

```
{"@sanity"} - this will run the scenario with all 3 examples
{"not @live"} - this will not run the scenario example tagged with @live (in this case for illustrative purposes the one tagged @ex2)
{"@live or @stage"} - this will run scenarios examples tagged with @live and @stage (in this case for illustrative purposes the ones tagged @ex1 & @ex2)
{"@test and @adhoc"} - this will only run the scenario example that has both @adhoc and @test tags (in this case for illustrative purposes the one tagged @ex3)
{"@test and (@stage or @adhoc)"} - this will run scenarios examples tagged with @test+@stage and @test+@adhoc (in this case for illustrative purposes the ones tagged @ex1 & @ex3)
```